# Icon color in MK FabButton

Tags: ios, swift, material-design

I'm using the MK pod (https://github.com/CosmicMind/MaterialKit) to try and place a fab button in my layout. The image I'm using is black. But the fab button appears to be overriding my icon color with a default color, because it shows up a faint blue color in the final fab button. Below are screenshots of the original image and the fab button with the image applied. Below are the only two lines I'm using to customize the fab button (I've subclassed it and made it IBDesignable, and the color I'm applying is one I've defined in a UIColor extension).

```
backgroundColor = UIColor.customBlueColor()
setImage(UIImage(named: "wifi"), forState: .Normal)
```

And here are the original icon and a screenshot of the result:

[image]  [image: screenshot]

How do I keep the original icon color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the tintColor property to adjust the icon color.

Example:

```
let img: UIImage? = UIImage(named: "wifi")
fabButton.setImage(img, forState: .Normal)
fabButton.setImage(img, forState: .Highlighted)
fabButton.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```

Also, to avoid the black highlight color that occurs when you press the FabButton, set the image to .Highlighted, as well as, .Normal.